# TableView crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

for some reason this UITableView keeps crashing and it seems like the UITableView is unable to display the secondsString for some reason but i have no idea why... please help me out here cause i have no idea what i could be doing wrong..... Thanks!!

```
#import "SettingsView.h"

@implementation SettingsView

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   transmissionSetup = [[TransmissionSetupViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TransmissionSetupViewController" bundle:nil];
   transmissionSetup.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
   NSLog(@"%i", [self getMinutes]);
   [self setSeconds:10];
   secondsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [self getSeconds]]; 
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

 #pragma mark Table view methods

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

   if (indexPath.section == 0) {
       cell.textLabel.text =  @"Every:";
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = secondsString;
    }
    // Set up the cell...

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: 2010-07-16 14:16:28.864 Navex[31130:207] 0
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

this is the error i get

Comment: I removed parts of code that are irrelevant to your problem - please try to avoid posting unnecessary code so it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your `secondString` with autoreleased string - so it is not guaranteed that it will be valid outside current scope.  You need to retain it upon initialization (and don't forget to release later)

I would advise you to have a look at objective-c [properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) for accessing ivars.

Comment: i intialized it in my header file like this: NSString *secondsSTring;
how do i retain it upon intialization?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text =  @"Every:";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = secondsString;
}
// Set up the cell...

return cell;
}
```